# How display colorful icon in phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar for wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How display colorful icon in phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar for wp8?

i want to Display a icon in the applicationbar, but It's not Display as an colorful Icon, just only base on the theme. if i have a Icon have five Color, how to Display?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to display a five color icon using ApplicationBar. If you really want to do it, you need to create your own component that looks and behaves like the ApplicationBar.